# RSA maximum message length with specific padding

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I'm trying to implement some encryption in my Java application.
The encryption should work as follows:

1. Generate random n bits AES key
2. Encrypt AES key using RSA public key
3. Send encrypted AES key to server
4. Encrypt data with AES key + send to server

I'm having trouble deciding what padding algorithm to use. I read `OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding` is a good choice, but what is the maximum message length I can encrypt with this?

I need to know the exact maximum bytes my AES key can be to be encrypted using RSA with `OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding`.

The length of the RSA key makes difference too. I will probably go for 2048 bits.

**TL;DR: How many bytes can I encrypt using a 2048 bits RSA key with `OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding`?**

Comment: I would consider [key + iv +  MAC-key] and for longer streams alternating key/iv pairs, in latter case the asym' key length would decide on how many symmetric key/iv pairs you can support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you describe is known as [Hybrid Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) and is a common way to get the speed of symmetric-key crypto systems combined with the benefits of the two keys of RSA.

**As for the specifics:**

A 2048 bit RSA key allows for 256 bytes of which the OAEP padding takes **`42`** bytes, leaving around 214 bytes for encrypted data. An AES-256 key is 256 bits (32 bytes) long, so there is plenty of space for it.

Comment: AES also supports key sizes of 128 ans 192 bits.

Comment: So the OAEP with SHA1 and MGF1 takes 42 bytes? If I were to use OAEP with SHA256 and MGF1, doesn't that use more bytes?

Comment: Is there any document to check the bytes these algorithms use? Or maybe a formula?

Comment: The OAEP padding size depends on the key size and message size on top of the OAEP parameters. The amount of padding is automatically extended to make the message and padding fit the key size. What Ebbe showed is the *minimum* amount of padding.

Comment: @kwantuM take a look [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112029/should-sha-1-be-used-with-rsa-oaep)